# UITableview returning incorrect index path row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a very simple 5 row table setup for a settings screen. Whenever the first cell is clicked it highlights but does not call the didselectrow. If I click a different row that row will call the did select function but return the incorrect row. I can then click the first row and it will return but also have an incorrect row. I have several tables set up in the project similar to this and they do not have this behavior. The cells are highlighting correctly, so I do not think that I have a layout/view problem. I don't have any constraint warnings and when I used the viewdebugger I did not encounter any views covering the table cells. All help is appreciated!

```
let settingsArray:[String] = ["Notifications","Account","bar","Help","Privacy Policy"]

extension SettingsViewController: UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return settingsArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("\(indexPath.row) setting \(settingsArray[indexPath.row])")
        if settingsArray[indexPath.row] != "bar" {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "settingOption") as! SettingsOptionCell
            cell.configure(setting: settingsArray[indexPath.row])
            self.settingsTable.rowHeight = 65
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "settingBar")
            self.settingsTable.rowHeight = 70
            cell?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            return cell!
        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("clicked \(indexPath.row)")
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
```

with

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
```

Comment: I've never felt so dumb!!! Thanks for the second set of eyes!

Comment: damn, I felt into same problem.. Waisted like 3 hours figuring it out what's wrong!! Thanks so much